# Classify Pixels using deep learning error 9999

Tags: arcgis-pro, error-999999, deep-learning

I'm trying to reproduce the Esri Super Resolution algorithm sample: https://developers.arcgis.com/python/samples/increase-image-resolution-using-superresolution/

I've successfully created the dlpk model and I'm trying to use the "Classify Pixels Using Deep Learning" tool, but the tool fails with a generic error 999999.

ArcGIS Pro version is 2.9.5, I've tried with different raster sources, but the error is always the same. I don't know if it's a useful information, but I also have a warning:

> 003054: Input Raster does not support PIXEL_SPACE (raw image space).
> Running in MAP_SPACE.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems but have recently upgraded to version 3.1.1 and now it works!

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. You need to provide details on your answer. Kindly take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). You can post as a comment.